# Why calculating ROC-AUC score with pure python takes too long?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I was trying to calculate Receiver Operating Characteristic Curve (ROC AUC) without using sklearn but the pure python, although I can get the correct score it takes too long like 10-15 mins (for approx 10k rows dataset) to print the output.
While using the sklearn inbuilt function it calculates quickly like in few seconds only.
If someone can help me to understand it.

Here is a sample code snippet.

```
Data =    y     pro
      0  1  0.123456
      1  1  0.035056
      2  0  0.226222
      3  0  0.412454
      4  1  0.121123

uniq = list(data.pro.unique())
actual =data.y
  
  tpr_list = []
  fpr_list = []
  for thr in uniq:
    y_pred = []
    for v in data.proba:
      if v <thr:
        y_pred.append(0)
      else:
        y_pred_auc.append(1)
    TP, FP, TN, FN=0, 0, 0, 0
    
    for i in range(len(uniq)):
      if y_pred[i] ==1 and actual[i] ==1:
        TP+=1
      elif y_pred[i] == 0 and actual[i] ==0:
        TN+=1
      elif y_pred_auc[i]==1 and actual[i] ==0:
        FP+=1
      else:
        FN+=1
```

using TP, FP, TN, FN; I have calculated AUC, I think that part is not required to understand the question so I removed it.

Thanks

Comment: We can only guess how [in]efficiently you implemented the logic only mentioned in the script above. The use of nested loops most likely also contribute.

Comment: Also, note that if your code (not shown in full here) works, this may be more suitable for [codereview.se]

Comment: Please show details. Reducing number of loops is usually better. And it also depends on what is inside the loop. You can debug/time the different parts of the code. Trying to exctract some calculus out of the loop / or in outermost loop can improve speed also.  Please show a full working piece of code you wrote for more ideas if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from efficiency from your side, regarding code complexity, scikit-learn uses Numpy for various operations, which is optimized in C code. I strongly doubt you can beat or get close to that with pure python, even if you write your code as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 1):

@desertnaut you actually can and with a vast margin.
I stumbled upon this problem myself and created a number of methods that are way faster than the standard sklearn realization. You can choose either of them depending on which suits you the most.

Python based is approximately **8X faster** than the default sklearn

Python+numba based is approximately **26X faster** than the default sklearn

C++/ctypes based is approximately **37X faster** than the default sklearn

The code is here: https://github.com/diditforlulz273/fastauc

10k simple AUC calculations run time with sklearn included:

[10k simple AUC calculations run time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHkhY.png)